# Vamos difundiendo nuestros blogs entre la hermandad de SOes

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio, comunidad

Espero se encuentren bien de salud y en todo aspecto de la vida y que en la programación todo les compile a la primera.

Les traigo esta idea y espero podamos unir fuerzas para expandir nuestra querida comunidad de StackOverflow en Español al infinito y más allá!

Para todos aquellos que tengan un blog o quieran iniciar uno, hagamos una lista y coloquemos un "blogroll" entre todos en cada sitio que tengamos. :D

La idea es que haya una sección en sus blogs/sitios web que contenga algo así:

```
Stack Overflow en español

Usuario 1 (enlace al perfil de usuario de SOes) - Blog (URL y/o titulo + URL) - Temática
Usuario 2 - Blog - Temática
...
Usuario N - Blog - Temática
```

¿Qué dicen? Conforme vayan comentando sus blogs, pueden agregarse a la lista.

> ## Actualización: Podrían agregar una temática/lenguaje de los que hablan en sus blogs/sitios web. Actualicen sus respuestas por favor :D

### Usuario - Blog/Website

1. [fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) - [Con todo el power 2.0!](http://fredyfx.com/blog) - Programación, Tecnologías Microsoft, Open Source, mucho ASP.net MVC, C#, opiniones sobre educación y sociedad.
2. [ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze) - [Blog Otecald](http://otecald.blogspot.com/)
3. [Juan Pinzón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2429/juan-pinz%C3%B3n) - [Legion Developers](https://www.legiondevelopers.ga/) - [Blog](https://juanpinzon-1992.blogspot.com/)
4. [Programmercito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/20441/programmercito) - [Blog](https://medium.com/@programmercito)
5. [awes0mem4n](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19623/awes0mem4n) - [Hijos del Spectrum](http://hijosdelspectrum.blogspot.com.es/)
6. [x4mp73r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2163/x4mp73r) - [Blog](https://x4mp73r.wordpress.com/blog/)
7. [paperbirdmaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster) - [[image]Vitamina C++](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/) - Blog de programación especializado en el lenguaje C++.
8. [SoftMolina](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/25004/softmolina) - [Blog](http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/)
9. [josego](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/20900/josego) - [Proyectos Beta](http://proyectosbeta.net/)
10. [astrojuanlu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/74/astrojuanlu) + [kikocorreoso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2816/kikocorreoso) - [Pybonacci](http://pybonacci.org/)
11. [jachguate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/21/jachguate) - [El blog de jachguate](https://jachguate.wordpress.com/)
12. [Peter Rojas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26386/peter-rojas) - [Monoforms](http://monoforms.com/)
13. [g3rv4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) - [**g3rv4** - A blog written by a *very* lucky nerd](https://g3rv4.com/)
14. [Jorny](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/32600/jorny) - [WiDroid](https://widroid.wordpress.com/) - Tutoriales de Android Studio organizado por temas y niveles.
15. [Mauro Petrini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2990/mauro-petrini) - [Blog personal](https://www.petrinimauro.com/) - Artículos de mi conocimiento en tecnologías backend, frontend y base de datos.
16. [Gonzalo Bianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) - [topcatarg](http://topcatarg.com.ar/) Artículos sobre varias tematicas relacionadas con las computadoras. en ingles.

Comment: Propongo: *Usuario - **temática/lenguaje** - Blog/Website*

Comment: Propongo sugerir cómo usar los votos a favor en contra.

Comment: Me parece muy bien incluir el vínculo al perfil del usuario pero  propongo evitar usar el nombre de usuario porque no es extraño que los usuarios cambie de nombre de usuario. Tal vez usar `usuario` como texto del enlace

Answer (score 5):

No es muy bueno mi blog, me da un poco de vergüenza... Más que el contenido, me centré en el estilo, poner mouse personalizado y el fondo de los robots. Aquí va.

[ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze?tab=profile) - [Blog Otecald](http://otecald.blogspot.com)

Comment: Muy bueno el artículo sobre [la importancia de enseñar](http://otecald.blogspot.mx/2016/10/la-importancia-de-ensenar.html).

Answer (score 5):

#### [PaperBirdMaster](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster) - [Vitamina C++](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/)

Lo actualizo mucho menos de lo que debería, pero cada año me propongo actualizarlo más.

La temática es C++, mi lenguaje favorito.

Comment: ¿Es posible ver una lista de las etiquetas de tu blog?

Comment: @Rubén la verdad... no estoy seguro de que NO se pueda, intentaré investigarlo.

Answer (score 4):

Yo estoy iniciando un pequeño blog, no tengo mucho contenido todavía, pero pienso ir posteando algunas cosas pronto

[Juan Pinzon](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2429/juan-pinz%C3%B3n) - [Legion Developers](https://www.legiondevelopers.ga/)

Anteriormente también compartí algo de contenidos en:

https://juanpinzon-1992.blogspot.com/

Las tematicas tratadas en los blogs son:

- Programación
- Seguridad Informática
- Tutoriales
- Recursos utiles como: libros, software, urls, entre otros.

En ambos tengo colocados los links a SO español.

Answer (score 4):

Hola yo apenas estoy comenzando un blog aun me faltan mucho contenido por compartir, y espero llegar a ser de un blog conocido y eficiente.

[SoftMolina Blog](http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/)

Answer (score 4):

Tengo un blog(Algo abandonado xD) que no tiene nada que ver con programación, son de relatos cortos. Un pasatiempo

[x4mp73r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2163/x4mp73r?tab=profile) - [Cuéntame una historia :D](https://x4mp73r.wordpress.com/blog/)

Answer (score 4):

mi blog :) 
https://medium.com/@programmercito

Answer (score 4):

Con un grupo tenemos un blog hace unos 8 años. Habla sobre muchos temas sobre tecnologia, abarcando temas de programacion, sistemas operativos, hardware etc.

El lema del blog es:

> En nuestra vida, desde que nacemos todo lo probamos, ensayamos y
>   testeamos; así también erramos, caemos pero por sobre todo aprendemos.
>   Es decir, todo lo que hacemos forma parte de una nueva experiencia, de
>   un PROYECTO. El que siempre exista la posibilidad de mejorarlo es lo
>   que lo convierte en BETA. En este blog queremos compartir contenidos
>   de tipo informático con artículos de programación, software libre y
>   propietario, redes, base de datos, noticias, experiencias, etc… y
>   también de humor. Es un sitio de todos y para todos. Participá! Sos
>   importante …

El blog se llama **Proyectos Beta**. Para [acceder](http://proyectosbeta.net/) al blog.

Answer (score 4):

[g3rv4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) - [g3rv4 | A blog written by a very lucky nerd](https://g3rv4.com) (en inglés)

Temática... como que no tengo. Arrancó como una forma de compartir soluciones a problemas nerds... y terminó siendo el lugar para compartir cosas... todo nerd, algo de python, c#, angular, asterisk...

No lo pensé como "un blog para seguir" sino más como "un blog para encontrar" :)

Answer (score 4):

A sugerencia de @fredyfx aquí os dejo el mío, claro empecé ayer pero lo ire alimentando día a día.

[Jorny](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/32600) - [widroid.wordpress.com](https://widroid.wordpress.com/) Blog de tutoriales desarrollados en Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tenemos @kikocorreoso y yo (entre otros) un blog llamado Pybonacci sobre Python científico en español :)

https://pybonacci.es/

Answer (score 3):

En mi blog, suelo hablar sobre Delphi, tecnología en general y, por qué no, sobre StackOverflow en Español:

http://jachguate.wordpress.com

Answer (score 3):

En mi blog hablo sobre programación y un poco administración de proyectos.
[Monoforms](http://monoforms.com/)

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 3):

## [Rubén](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/65/) - [Rubén Rivera](https://www.rubenrivera.mx)

---

Luego de que Google aprobara mi primer complemento para hojas de cálculo de Google moví mi "landing page" de un Google Site a Blogger a donde estoy pasando el contenido más visitado de *Ejemplos para foros*, el cual les había compartido originalmente en esta misma respuesta.

P.D. En [Les presento Visor de Registros](https://www.rubenrivera.mx/2018/08/les-presento-visor-de-registros.html) cuento sobre el complmento citado.

---

[Ejemplos para foros](https://sites.google.com/site/ejemplosparaforos/)

Hace tiempo inicié un sitio que incluye un "blog" para tratar de evitar repetirme a mi mismo, lo llamé "El blog rápido y sucio"... me parece que hace honor a su nombre XD

La temática principalmente es sobre aplicaciones de Google, la mayoría de las publicaciones han sido sobre

- Google Apps Script
- Hoja de Cálculo
- Documentos
- Google Sites

Answer (score 3):

Sé que la invitación era para @fredyfx aún así voy a compartir mis blogs porque me pareció interesante y divertido esto.

[mispasosporelplanetatierra](https://mispasosporelplanetatierra.blogspot.com/) ----> `Cuentos cortos de ciencia ficción o fantasía.`

[medium.com/@Mariyselita](https://medium.com/@Mariyselita/la-computadora-es-un-mundo-d962019bd75f) ----> `Proyecto donde hablo de mi historia con la informática.`

[mariyselita](https://mariyselita.blogspot.com/) ----> `Blog personal.`

Answer (score 2):

Yo tengo uno que habla de más cosas que sólo programación. Si te interesa es este:

[Hijos del Spectrum](http://hijosdelspectrum.blogspot.com.es/)

Answer (score 2):

Aca les dejo el mismo, fresquito y recien iniciado

[A blog about things that appens around a computer](http://topcatarg.com.ar)

Answer (score 1):

Este blog no es mío. Lo comparto porque considero que tiene tutoriales excelentes para quienes programan en Android:

[hermosaprogramacion.com](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com)

Su autor se llama James Arevalo.

Answer (score 1):

[alfabravo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6798/alfabravo) - General/cosas geeks/escritos varios (todo en español) - [Blog personal "Verba volant, scripta manent"](https://alfabravoteam.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 1):

Dueño: [Arcanis - The Omnipotent](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/46896)

- Learn More and Have Fun - LMHF / Blog / Filosofía, Artículos Random  (Link).
- City of Knowledge / Sitio Web / Q&A Tecnología, Ingeniería y Arquitectura (Link).
- El Bastión de Algarbe / Discord / Juegos, Role Play, Tecnología ([Link](https://discord.gg/cYGSKm4jRw)).
- ATSU - Advanced Toolkit for Stack Overflow Users / Extensión ([Link](https://github.com/IcarosNetSA/atsu)).