# Colaborar a los que buscan ayuda

Tags: discusión, preguntas, recursos

He notado hace mucho que llegan muchos usuarios en busca de ayuda, con una pregunta amplia, que no abarca un problema de programación, sino más bien, dudas acerca de:

- Qué lenguaje es mejor para esta o aquella cosa
- Qué camino seguir para aprender a desarrollar aplicaciones móviles
- Qué IDE y/o editor es mejor

Las tres anteriores son las que más puedo ver.

Esto se me vino a la mente luego de ver actitudes un poco ásperas, rústicas o como quieran llamarlas de ciertos usuarios, no sé quienes son, que solo buscan dar puntos negativos a cualquier cosa que no vaya acorde al reglamento.

Pero sería interesante que si llegan personas con dudas tales como las expuestas arriba, y no sé cuál más conozcan ustedes, que se pueda recomendar usuarios que a través de sus propios blogs, páginas, repositorios, canales de Youtube o donde tengan uno, dirigirlos, o tener una lista creada, y que especifique que tipo de información, podrá encontrar en cada uno.

[image: compartir]

En la siguiente imagen dejo ennumerado el como aparecen las cosas cuando se va a realizar una pregunta:

1. Input o caja de texto
2. Lista de sugerencia
3. Area para escribir la pregunta
4. Una lista de opciones

[image: mockup]

Lo que yo digo es que, si la pregunta engloba cierto tipo como las que expongo dentro de esta, que en vez de salir preguntas recomendadas solo pro poner la palabra **app**, **web** o cualquier otra cosa, como el nombre de un lenguaje de programacion, salgan recomendaciones de los usuarios o de los sitios o canales de estos, o en su defecto un solo algo que diga:

***Deseas aprender algo, dirígete a este sección***

Y en la sección, estén los usuarios, sus enlaces, y al lado como las temáticas que estos hablan.

Comment: ¿Te refieres algo así como un mega-repositorio de enlaces colaborativo de toda la hermandad? Tengo uno personal de acceso público: http://fredyfx.com/resources espero les sea de utilidad :D

Comment: @fredyfx algo así, pero metería algo como que si busca desarrollos de app moviles, entonces aparezcan como personas que tienen repositorio y tales como los tuyos, y que se pegue una pasada, no se si en los perfiles dejan poner información de tal tipo

Comment: ¿Ya viste [Vamos difundiendo nuestros blogs entre la hermandad de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1203/65)?

Comment: @Rubén viendo que no sabia

Comment: @Rubén muy bueno, solo falta el poder agregar algo como si fuera una sección mas en la comunidad aquí en español, no se que dirán los jefes

Comment: Me parecía muy bien todo lo que estabas diciendo, pero a partir de "*que se pueda recomendar usuarios que a través de sus propios blogs...*" me confunde un poco lo que estás discutiendo... Es decir, son preguntas que se tienen que mejorar o cerrar, ¿en eso estamos de acuerdo, no? ¿Y que es lo que estás diciendo de hacer? ¿La idea que estás proponiendo es darle muchos links en comentarios?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Mariano. Yo en ese tipo de preguntas suelo poner un comentario indicando donde se puede buscar ayuda o poniendo algún enlace a tutoriales o librerias. Y seguidamente procedo a su cierre. Lo primero es cortesía, ya que me gusta poder ayudar al que tiene alguna duda. Lo segundo está mas que discutido, ese tipo de preguntas no tienen cabida aqui en mi opinión.

Comment: Probablemente un buen lugar donde poner recomendaciones sea la página wiki de las etiquetas.

Comment: @fedorqui pues si, yo creo que ahi deberian ir. En los comentarios que se pongan en la publicacion, como dice Pikoh, deberia ser algo como *"Mira la pagina de [tag:etiqueta] para ver enlaces y recomendaciones"*

Comment: @fedorqui totalmente de acuerdo, la wiki de cada etiqueta es el sitio ideal para poder poner enlaces útiles

Comment: Por cierto, [un ejemplo de lo que hablamos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/146411/15301), en el que además parece que mi comentario anima al OP a pensar que tiene razón. A veces es contraproducente tratar de ayudar en los comentarios...

Comment: @Pikoh probablemente tu comentario era de "baja calidad" :-P

Comment: @Mariano de eso no tengo ninguna duda ;)

Comment: @Mariano que mas tiempo sin verte, no nada de poner muchos links en preguntas para cerrar, solo que si la persona por ejemplo, va hacer un pregunta como, *como aprendo C#*, por ejemplo, seria interesante que en el campo de busqueda automaticamente este reconozca que la pregunta es por decir *incontestable*, y que en el espacio sea del lado derecho carguen los perfiles de los usuarios que tienen **blogs** o **canales de youtube** que enseñan algo.

Comment: @lois6b [tag:etiqueta] no tiene wiki de etiqueta ni preguntas :P

Comment: Bueno revisen ahora lo que coloque, espero se entienda mas.

Comment: @Pedro tanto tiempo! totalmente! Creo que ahora estoy entendiendo mejor... Sería muy interesante que que el sistema reconozca una pregunta incontestable, sin duda... Pero me imagino que si pudiesen reconocerlo, ya lo hubiesen implementado para que no permita preguntar, no?

Comment: Lástima que el proyecto "Documentation" fue cancelado.

Comment: @Rubén usted lo ha dicho

Comment: @Mariano pues de poder se puede, sabe el gobierno lo que escribimos, ahora que no podamos, empezar a sacar preguntas con que digan cosas como, *que debo aprender para saber programar*, eso ya seria para bloquear el área de escribir la pregunta.

Comment: Reemplacé [meta-tag:centro-de-ayuda] por [meta-tag:preguntas] pues esta discusión se ha centrado en la página de publicación de preguntas

Answer (score 1):

> ...solo que si la persona por ejemplo, va hacer un pregunta como, como aprendo C#, por ejemplo, seria interesante que en el campo de busqueda automaticamente este reconozca que la pregunta es por decir *incontestable*, y que en el espacio sea del lado derecho carguen los perfiles de los usuarios que tienen **blogs** o **canales de youtube** que enseñan algo.

## Comentario corto

¿Te refieres a que SOES haga lo que ya hace Google?

## Comentario extendido

Al googlear "que lenguaje es mejor para programar" (nótese que falta acento a la primer palabra) se muestra

- Pestañas Todo, Videos, Imágenes Noticias, Maps, Más, etc.
- Un fragmento de búsqueda destacado
- Preguntas relacionadas
- Resultados en orden de relevancia según la "receta secreta" de "la casa"
- Búsquedas relacionadas

[image: Parte superior de resultados de búsqueda]

[image: Parte inferior de resultados de búsqueda]

Comment: Pues ruben algo así, pero si es dentro del sitio, que recomiende los usuarios que poseen ya material de aprendizaje desarrollados por ellos, claro, no es que nos volvamos google.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales no está descabellado "que nos volvamos Google", pero especializado en la temática del sitio y los miembros de la comunidad, de hecho Google con un "custom search engine" podría limitarse el contenido a contenido y usuarios de SOES como ya "casi" se hace en [se], aunque a este le falta incluir varias cosas de las que hablamos

Comment: Pues interesante, no sabia que se podía limitar lo de la búsqueda del motor de búsqueda, bueno esperemos a ver si lo podemos lograr

Comment: Hola, disculpen mi intromisión. Pero según recuerdo, precisamente Google permite realizar búsquedas en sitios específicos: partiendo porque nos ofrece un widget de buscador para ponerlo en nuestros propios sitios web, como que al poner en la búsqueda del Google principal: `site:http://www.misitio.com`, la búsqueda la realiza sólo dentro de ese dominio... Por lo que no sería malo aprovechar la IA de Google en estos casos...

Comment: @quinqui Está es una conversación abierta, no hace falta disculparse por participar. ¿Se te ocurre algo para enriquecer la propuesta de Pedro o mi respuesta?

Comment: @Rubén Pues yo creo que precisamente lo que ya puse en mi comentario. O sea, como una propuesta, probar el buscador de Google respecto al requerimiento de Pedro. Él pide que aparezca embebido en el formulario de nueva pregunta, no sé si eso se puede hacer, me refiero a modificar dicho formulario (pero como lo está pidiendo, supongo que sí). Es una idea, claro, basada en el uso del buscador de Google que conozco y que tú mismo has descrito en tu respuesta. Ahora, que cómo funciona en modo desarrollador, no lo sé.

Answer (score 1):

Para eso sirven las descripciones de las etiquetas, para poner referencias a toda la información pertinente. Siéntete libre de mejorar las descripciones y agregar referencias a todo tipo de artículos relacionados.

En SOen he visto algunas descripciones de temas que incluyen:

- página oficial
- libros recomendados
- videos relacionados
- historia
- diferencias con otros conceptos
- comparación con elementos similares y/o relacionados

Ahora en concreto respecto a las preguntas de ejemplo

- Qué lenguaje es mejor para esta o aquella cosa
- Qué camino seguir para aprender a desarrollar aplicaciones móviles
- Qué IDE y/o editor es mejor

Se basan en opiniones, y como no tenemos exactamente las mismas capacidades cognitivas, solamente podemos adivinar lo que perceptualmente es mejor para una persona que no expone los criterios de referencia.
Las preguntas podrían ser re-escritas de una manera más puntual como

- que lenguaje es mejor *en desempeño* para esta o aquella cosa
- qué conceptos debo de aprender para desarrollar aplicaciones móviles usando el lenguaje de programación X si deseo desarrollar una aplicación que me permita realizar lo siguiente: etc...
- Qué IDE y/o editor es recomendado para desarrollar videojuegos de Unity3D y que cumpla por lo menos con los sigiuenes requerimientos que necesito: etc...

Comment: Claro, es que lo que digo yo no es algo permanente, solo di el partir de una idea, por eso digo, se trata de saber si es posible armar algo al respecto, para que al momento de que escriban cosas tales como esas que es mejor o cosas pro el estilo, ls salga algo para que vayan y lean y no escriban sin mas.