# ¡Felices fiestas! ¿Cómo lo váis a celebrar?

Tags: discusión

Que paséis unas buenas fiestas, disfrutad, descansad y no hardcodeéis demasiado.

¿Cómo váis a celebrar las fiestas este año?

Comment: Superando la tristeza cuando nadie responde a mis preguntas Jajaja.

Comment: @MiguelClavijo, publícalo como respuesta. Que si que cuela.

Answer (score 8):

Yo seguiré haciendo lo mismo que siempre he hecho cada día durante todos los últimos años: *intentar conquistar el mundo...*. Se ve que no se me da bien, pero no dejaré de intentarlo, sobre todo durante las fiestas, ya que el mundo se relaja.

Comment: Tengo entendido que tener un clon maligno en miniatura ayuda mucho, suerte con tu conquista el año 2020 ;-D

Comment: seguro te vas a cantar [Villancicos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villancico) de puerta en puerta

Answer (score 8):

No sé si yo vaya a celebrarlo, estoy en modo *Grinch*. A no ser que me traigan los *chasquiboom* o alguna otra cosa.

Ya no venden naranjúes para juntar piedritas abajo de los toboganes y en mi casa no pusieron el arbolito ni luces parpadeantes.

#### Actualización

Compré los chasquibum, los estallé todos en la pared y el techo de mi hogar, fue divertido.

Answer (score 7):

Superando la tristeza cuando nadie responde a mis preguntas Jajaja.

Answer (score 7):

Con la familia y seres queridos ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yo me la pasé, compartiendo con la familia. Y leyendo como se la han pasado ustedes.

Felicidades a tod@s.

Answer (score 5):

Yo me pienso pegar una viciada legendaria a la PS4.

Comment: ¿Que Juego? :-o

Comment: Todo lo que no he podido jugar durante el año, tengo en la recámara Days Gone, Bloodstained y si me porto bien espero que los reyes me traigan el Fallen Order

Comment: Muy bueno el _Days Gone_, la primer horda la padecí horas

Answer (score 5):

Jugando un torneo de MK, y lamentablemente lejos de mi PC :(

Answer (score 5):

Pensando como entregar el proyecto el 2 de enero luego de celebrar 31 y 1

Comment: ¡Suerte con ese proyecto, y feliz año!

Answer (score 5):

Aquí en Bolivia, a las 20:00 del 31/12/2019 (-04:00), con mi esposa e hijas acompañandome en el lanzamiento de un emprendimiento personal, y leyendo respuestas de la comunidad StackOverflow en español.

Feliz año a todo este equipo en el cual colaboramos como miembros de una familia programadora. Un abrazo para todos!

PD: 01 de enero, Dia de vivir al máximo tu videojuego favorito.

Answer (score 4):

Una hora de Gran Turismo Sport en la PS4, comer lo que no he comido suficiente en esta navidad y a cenar con la novia, su familia y mi madre. :)

Answer (score 4):

Tengo un [blog](https://mariyselita.blogspot.com/2019/12/agradecimiento-2010-2019.html) y siempre celebro escribiendo un agradecimiento a las personas que lo hicieron un buen año. Lo tengo desde 2008 así que es una tradición, no importa donde esté, así celebro siempre (:

Mañana es fin de año, estaré diseñando algunas cosas por la mañana, y por la noche iré a visitar a mi familia.

Comment: Blog solo para invitados ?

Comment: Así es jeje lo que ocurre es que se volvió demasiado personal, pero si encuentra algún interés en leerlo lo puedo dejar abierto por un momento o pedir acceso sin problemas (:

Comment: en mis más de 15 años de blogger, primera vez que veo un blog solo para invitados :D todos los días se aprende algo nuevo :D

Comment: Sí, de hecho jeje

Comment: @fredyfx [Vamos difundiendo nuestros blogs entre la hermandad de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1203)